# string to number conversion in golang

Tags: go

Golang has [strconv](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/) library that converts string to int64 and uint64.

However, the rest of integer data types seems to be unsupported as I can't find conversion functions for byte, int16, uint16, int32, uint32 data types.

One can always convert from byte, 16-bit and 32-bit data types to int64 and uint64 without loss of precision.  Is that what's intended by language?

Comment: yes, convert to uint64 or int64, then encode to string.

Comment: Use fmt.Sprintf() to convert any integer type to string

Comment: `[]byte(s)` to set a string to a slice of uint8 or `[]rune(s)` to set a string to a slice of int32. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546. `string([]byte(s))` or `string([]rune(s))` to set a slice of bytes or runes to a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725637/12817546 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62739051/12817546.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the docs a bit more closely you can use this method;

```
func ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int)
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt

The `bitSize` argument says how large the int is so you can do `8` or `16` or `32` for those smaller integer types. `Atoi` calls this internally. I believe you're wanting `10` for the `base` argument. So like `b, err := strconv.ParseInt("5", 10, 8)` for a byte.

EDIT: Just going to add a couple things to the answer here in case the OP is in fact confused how to convert a 16-bit int into a string... If that is your intended goal just use `fmt.Sprintf` or you can do a conversion from smaller int to larger int as it will always succeed. Examples of both [here](https://play.golang.org/p/UWSVxEmQ1N);

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    var a int16
    a = 5
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%d", a)
    s2 := strconv.Itoa(int(a))
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(s2)
}
```

Comment: `ParseInt` converts *from* a string to an integer.   The question is asking about the other direction - converting *to* a string.

Comment: @zmb I highly doubt that. The issue of size is only relevant when going from a string to the number types. Strings are unbounded in size (except by your cpu's memory) so I can obviously convert any type of number in the language to a string without having to consider any of this. I also, don't need to use a special library like `strconv` the methods in `fmt` are perfectly sufficient. Lastly, if I have an 32-bit int and a 'itoa' method that only works for 64-bit as the OP points out it's very obvious what needs to be done which is a cast to `(int64)` which will always succeed...

Comment: How doesn't it?  The question is titled "number to string conversion" and then says "strconv converts int64 and uint64 to string".

Comment: @zmb I assumed the OP is confused due to that question not making any sense. The amount of bytes occupied by a number obviously has no bearing on the conversion to string... Anyway, in response to your comment I updated to explain conversions in either direction then got downvoted ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I think the OP is confused too, just for a different reason.  Perhaps (s)he doesn't know about the fmt package.  You've got my upvote in either case :)

Answer (score 3):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    n := int16(42)
    s := strconv.FormatInt(int64(n), 10)
    fmt.Printf("n %d s %q\n", n, s)
}
```

Output:

```
n 42 s "42"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert any int type to string using fmt.Sprintf() method

```
var num int64
numstring:=fmt.Sprintf("%d",num)
```

Comment: Top-notch answer that I quoted. Did I add to it? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725637/12817546