# Go: Reading JSON file vs. Reading JSON string

Tags: json, parsing, go

I have a JSON file called `example.json` that looks like:

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "type": "record"
}
```

I also have a variable representing the above as a "string":

```
const example = `{
    "name": "example",
    "type": "record",
}`
```

I am trying to understand why reading the contents of the JSON file into bytes is different from reading the contents of the `example` variable. My code is as follows:

```
    bytesJSON, err := ioutil.ReadFile("example.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    bytesVar, err := json.Marshal(example)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

Both are of the type `[]uint8`, but look very different. Any ideas on why? And how I can make sure that they are always the same?

EDIT: Even using `bytesVar := []byte(example)` results in the same issue.

EDIT:

`bytesJSON` looks like:

[123 10 32 32 32 32 34 110 97 109 101 34 58 32 34 101 120 97 109 112 108 101 34 44 10 32 32 32 32 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 32 34 114 101 99 111 114 100 34 10 125]

`bytesVar` looks like:

[34 112 117 98 115 117 98 95 101 120 97 109 112 108 101 95 116 111 112 105 99 34]

when printed to `stdout`.

Comment: They are _obviously_ different. The `json.Marshal` returns the content as a JSON encoded string and not a raw string

Comment: @Inian `bytesVar := []byte(example)` behaves the same way. How can I read the variable as a raw string into bytes instead?

Comment: After `json.Marshal` you get a json-encoded string. What do you mean  "they look different" without marshaling? What is in bytesJSON and what is in bytesVar?

Comment: @BurakSerdar updated the question to depict what they look like.

Comment: Your `bytesVar` does not match what's in `example`. It says `"pubsub_example_topic"`. And `bytesJSON` has a lot of extra stuff in it. Did you get your examples right?

Comment: Oops! will fix them now. Sorry.

Comment: @walksignison Thanks, but `bytesVar` is still incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: The "edit" output in the question is using different example input than in the question.*

If we print them as strings it becomes clear.

```
fmt.Println(string(bytesJSON))

{
    "name": "example",
    "type": "record",
}
```

`ioutil.ReadFile` is just what's in the file.

```
fmt.Println(string(bytesVar))

"{\n        \"name\": \"example\",\n        \"type\": \"record\",\n    }"
```

[`json.Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) has encoded the string `example` as JSON. That is a JSON string containing a string.

The equivalent to `ioutil.ReadFile("example.json")` is simply `example`.

If we unmarshal `bytesVar` we get back the original string in `example`.

```
var unmarshal string;
json.Unmarshal(bytesVar,&unmarshal)
fmt.Println(unmarshal)

{
        "name": "example",
        "type": "record",
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. But, `ioutil.ReadFile("example.json")` returns bytes - while `example` is of string type. Is there a way for me to get the equivalent of `example` in bytes?

Comment: @walksignison [How to assign string to bytes array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032170/how-to-assign-string-to-bytes-array). I'd recommend giving [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) and [Go By Example](https://gobyexample.com/) a... go.